# Javascript regular expression difficulty, match string against a name

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a name obtained from server against input provided by a user, the complete name may or may not be known entirely by the user, for example I should be able to match the following:

> Name Obtained: Manuel Barrios Pineda
>   Input given: Manuel P

Right until now I've tried with this code:

```
var name_obtained = 'Manuel Barrios Pineda';
var re = new RegExp('\b[' + name_obtained + ']+\b');
var input_string = 'Manuel';

if (input_string.match(re)) {
    alert('Match');
} else {
    alert('No Match');
}
```

Here's an example:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KhqLu/)

EDIT 1:
It's required to match input like 'Manuel B', 'Manuel P'

Comment: Double escape the `b`. `new RegExp('\\b[' + name_obtained + ']+\\b');` String literal syntax has escape sequences as well, so to use a  `\b` in the regex, you need to provide a literal `\ ` character, which is done with `\\ `.

Comment: What specifically is the regex testing against? After fixing by double-escaping, or just removing them, it'll match `"Manuel Pinzon"`, too.

Comment: if you can implement a full text search you can put string matching on your db instead in your application logic

Comment: Ok, I double-escaped that, it's "working" now, but as Dave Newton noticed input like 'Manuel Bartender' would match, any ideas how could the regex be more restrictive. @DaveNewton regex should match combinations like 'Manuel B', 'Manuel P'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this

```
var input_given = 'Manuel P'.replace(/[.+*()\[\]]/g, ' ').replace(/\?/g, '.'),
    name_obtained = 'Manuel Barrios Pineda',
    arr = input_given.split(' '), i, ret = true;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length && ret; ++i) // for each word A in input
    if (arr[i]) // skip ""
        ret = new RegExp('\\b' + arr[i]).test(name_obtained);
            // test for word starting A in name
// if test failed, end loop, else test next word

if (ret) alert('Match'); // all words from input in name
else alert('No Match');  // not all words found
```

Comment: Tried your solution and it is working like a charm, though I'm still trying to understand exactly how you achieved it as I'm a newbie when it comes to regular expressions.

Comment: The first line sanitises the input, it then tests each word in the input to see if the name contains words (that start, at least) with words from the input :)

Comment: The `for` loop is a little more complicated that normal, notice the `&& ret`; i.e. it ends if `ret` becomes false.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> var name_obtained = 'Manuel Barrios Pineda';
> var re = new RegExp('\b[' + name_obtained + ']+\b');
> ```

That's not working. Your building a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match a single character between word boundaries. The result will be equal to

```
var re = /\b[adeilnoruBMP]\b/;
```

> ```
> input_string.match(name_obtained)
> ```

That would never work when the `name_obtained` is longer than the `input_string`. Notice that [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will try to find the regex *in* the `input_string`, not the other way round.

Therefore I'd suggest to use something simple like

```
var name_obtained = 'Manuel Barrios Pineda';
var input_string = 'Manuel';

if (name_obtained.indexOf(input_string) > -1) {
    alert('Match');
} else {
    alert('No Match');
}
```

To use your `input_string` as a regex to search in the obtained name with omitting middle names or end characters, you could do

```
String.prototype.rescape = function(save) {
    return this.replace(/[{}()[\]\\.?*+^$|=!:~-]/g, "\\$&");
}

var name_obtained = 'Manuel Barrios Pineda';
var input_string = 'Manuel'; // or 'Manuel P', 'Manuel Pineda', 'Manuel B', 'Barrios P', …

var re = new RegExp("\\b"+input_string.rescape().split(/\s+/).join("\\b.+?\\b"));
if (re.test(name_obtained)) {
    alert('Match');
} else {
    alert('No Match');
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I should be able to match something like 'Manuel P', 'Manuel Pineda', 'Manuel B', etc

Comment: I tried your code, it won't match any input string, perhaps I missed something.